# not able to view JSON file from browser

Tags: angular2-routing

I am trying to view json file from the browser

http://localhost:4200/app/dynamic/dashboard.json

but its redirecting to http://localhost:4200

file is present at the location

while calling from http.get i am getting 404 error, not sure why .

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try relative path to get the file? (like "./path/file.json")

Comment: yes, i tried, same 404 error

Answer (score 0):

got solution, I am using Angular-CLI ,JSON file should be in Assets directory it seems.